# Modifying phone number variable from Active Directory in Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, active-directory

We have a Powershell script to automatically create outlook signatures using data pulled from Active Directory.

Currently we're pulling in phone numbers with the following line:

```
Update-Sig -attribute "TelephoneNumber" -value "$([string]($ADUser.TelephoneNumber))"
```

This will return a number in the format +61112345678.

What I want to do is change that string so that it's always in the format +61 1 1234 5678 with spaces.

Is this possible? I'm thinking I need to take the string, turn it into a variable and then add a space after a certain amount of characters.. but i'm unsure how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: I'll do this in two comments because of character limitation. `TelephoneNumber` is a string attribute for an AD user. In fact, the PowerShell name for that attribute is `OfficePhone` whereas the LDAP name is `telephoneNumber`. Since this is a string, there is no telling in what format it was entered at some point. You have tested and saw that for one user it returned `+61112345678`, but that does not mean this format was applied for all users..

Comment: I'm afraid that your code will have to decide if the string value starts with a `+` sign so what follows _should be_ a country code. However, since the list of [Country Calling Codes](https://countrycode.org/) is quite extensive, it can be very hard to define the correct code, but if you're in luck, most of your users are in Australia (code 61). In pseudo code, you check if the string starts with `+`, then remove all non-digits from the remaining part using `$number -replace '\D',''` and format that using @Lee_Dailey answer.

Comment: Hi @Theo, yes all the numbers will start with +612.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the string format operator to do that. it has a "number placeholder" option. however, that only works on actual *numbers* and your data is almost certainly a string. so ... i converted the numeric part to an `[int64]`. [*grin*]

```
$SourceValue = '+61112345678'
'+{0:## # #### ####}' -f ([int64]$SourceValue.TrimStart('+'))
```

output = `+61 1 1234 5678`

Comment: Hey,

Just to be clear, the number is in that format without spaces, but it doesn't always return +61112345678, it reutrns whatever $ADUser.TelephoneNumber is.

I tried changing the number to a variable and I get  "Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @MarcusB - what is in the value that you are feeding to the code i posted? if it is a string that starts with a `+` and has only numbers in it, then it _should_ work. so ... how are you calling the code i posted?

Comment: I tried calling it by putting your block of code after the Update-Sig command I posted above and doing `$SourceValue = "TelephoneNumber"
'+{0:## # #### ####}' -f ([int64]$SourceValue.TrimStart('+'))`

Comment: @MarcusB - well ... `TelephoneNumber` is a string of characters. [*grin*] i think you would need to use `$ADUser.TelephoneNumber` as the input to the string format operator.

Comment: @MarcusB - ok, what _exactly_ does `$ADUser.TelephoneNumber` return?

Comment: $ADUser is just a variable which returns the AD User, then Telephone Number returns the Telephone Number attribute of that user which is passed as a string I believe.

Comment: @MarcusB - yes, i know that. [*grin*] but WHAT is the value in the `.TelephoneNumber` property? the point here is that the code i posted **_only works on data in the format you showed_**. it will NOT work on anything other than `<plus sign><some number of digits>`. so ... what is the value in the property that is failing to work with the code i posted?

Comment: Hey, that's what it is returning but maybe i'm a little bit confused where to implement it. I've uploaded the script so you can have a look if you'd be so kind! [Automatic Outlook Signature](https://codepad.co/snippet/JFGO49gI)

Comment: i cannot test it since i have no AD access. however, on line 69 the `-Value` parameter apparently can be replaced with this `'+{0:## # #### ####}' -f ([int64]($ADUser.TelephoneNumber.TrimStart('+')))`. either that, or make a temporary $Var to hold that value and use that $Var with the `-Value` parameter. ///// i STRONGLY recommend you edit your code to insert a `write-host` & then a `pause` so you can see what the value is when you call the code. use basic diagnostics ... [*grin*]

Comment: So changing the value parameter to that line just changes the output of TelephoneNumber to that line instead of taking the phone number.

Comment: @MarcusB - you **_STILL_** have not shown me the EXACT value that is in one of the `.TelephoneNumber` properties AND that is not working with the code i posted.

Comment: as above, an example would be +61282632461.

Comment: @MarcusB - something in your data is not as expected. you will need to find out what that is. when i use your new sample string thus `$SourceValue = '+61282632461'`, and run this code `'+{0:## # #### ####}' -f ([int64]$SourceValue.TrimStart('+'))`, i get this result `+61 2 8263 2461`. ///// so that means there is something about your data that is not as expected. i can't test that for you, so you will need to start looking. try running `.GetType()` on it, or feeding it into `Format-Hex` to see if there are any non-printing chars in it. ///// good luck! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Credits for this should go to @Lee_Daily because of the string format.
You can do something like below to format the expected '+61' numbers and if there is something else in the property it will print it out so you can check.

```
$phone = '+61112345678'

# test if the string starts with a `+` or at least the digits `61`
if ($phone.Trim() -match '^(\+|61)') {
    $phone = '+{0:## # #### ####}' -f ([int64]($phone -replace '\D',''))
    Write-Host "Formatted TelephoneNumber: '$phone'" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else {
    # not a '+61' number. Write it out so you can check/correct manually
    Write-Host "Unexpected TelephoneNumber: '$phone'" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

To answer your latest comment, indeed, the code above does not *set* the newly formatted telephone number in the ADUser's attribute.
I thought the question was all about the formatting, not the setting.

Although your link is broken, it would be easy enough to set this in the AD.
It seems you already have an object called `$ADUser` and I imagine this came from an earlier `Get-ADUser` call you did.
Setting the formatted number you obtained using the above code, you can simply update the users number using for instance:

```
# using piping the user object to Set-ADUser
$ADUser | Set-ADUser -OfficePhone $phone

# using one of the users properties as 'Identity' and update using the LDAP attribute name
# for parameter Identity, the cmdlet accepts either the DistinguishedName, objectGUID, objectSid, or the SamAccountName
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.DistinguishedName -Replace @{telephoneNumber = $phone }
```

p.s. There is also an attribute called `HomePhone` (LDAP name `homePhone`), but that is not the one you use in your code.

Hope that helps

Comment: This appears to say it work but not actually update the telephone number as expected. Most likely the things you and @Lee_Dailey have suggested are spot on, but I think given the nature of the Find/Replace code it's probably overriding what you're doing. The script is here if you want to see [https://codepad.co/snippet/JFGO49gI](Automatic Outlook Signature).

If you look at lines 49-66, that's where the replacing is happening.

Comment: @MarcusB I have added code for updating the users telephone number. Although your link is broken (404), I think this wil help you.